# How can I train my cat to stay in the yard when outside?

Tags: cats, training

I have a problem with my cat George. Yesterday night George snuck out of the house. Twice when he was let out he wanders 2 miles south of where I live.

After the 2nd time we got him fixed and he stopped wandering. We would let him out and he would stay in the yard or around it.

Today he ran off again. I don't know if he is just roaming around my house or if he ran off back to that one house 2 miles out.

How can I train him to stay in the yard?

Comment: If you're going to let cats out unsupervised, you really can't set a limit on how far they go. That isn't "running away", it's being a cat and exploring its environment.

Answer (score 1):

If he keeps running away, lock the door when you leave your home and if ever outside, be sure that he is being supervised, for he may run away again.

Is your cat a barn cat? Because if it is, barn cats do have a risk of running away. Another suggestion is raising him as an indoor cat. If a cat is raised a certain way for a long time, it will eventually act as what it is raised as;either barn cat or indoor/house cat.

Hope this helped!